# Contradicting exceptions when passing file to another method

Tags: java, file, exception

I'm trying to pass a file to another method which takes a String as its argument, but when I compile it I get contradicting exceptions.

The method I'm calling is:

```
public static String sortThis(String inputFileName) 
{
//code here
}
```

The code where I'm calling the method is:

```
tempFile1 = Sort2.sortThis(tempFile2.getPath());
```

and I get the exception:

```
incompatible types
Found: java.lang.String
Required: java.io.File
```

So if I just pass the file:

```
tempFile1 = Sort2.sortThis(tempFile2);
```

I get:

```
sortThis(java.lang.String) in Sort2 cannot be applied to (java.io.File)
```

Am I using the wrong method of File to get the file name/path? I'm not sure what the difference is between getAbsolutePath(), getCanonicalPath(), and getPath(), so that could be the reason it's acting strangely?

Comment: Can you post more of the code for `sortThis`?

Comment: sortThis appears to return a String, where tempFile1 is File. You can't assign a String to a File.

Comment: Ah, yes, got it - it does return a String, that was the problem. Worked that out from Jonathon's post just before you posted Hunter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your `tempFile1` is of type `File` instead of `String`

The following compiles and works.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        File file = new File( "" );
        String tempFile1 = Test.sortThis( file.getPath() );
        System.out.println( tempFile1 );
    }

    public static String sortThis( String inputFileName )
    {
        return inputFileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it from that - it was that sortThis returns a String.